# Trying to explain a a java nested loop which checks for a network connection

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, connection

I'm trying to do a written report on some code and I found one on Youtube. However I don't understand how this loop works. I understand that it must return a `boolean` value which then goes into another method but if someone could breakdown what is happening it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Loop {
    public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some comments for understanding:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
//making the object
if (connectivityManager!=null){ //if it was instantiated
    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo(); //it makes an array of all of the network info
    if (info != null) { //if this worked (if there's info)
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++){ //looping through data
            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
            //if the state of any of the objects is equal to connected (if device is connected)
                return true; //the device is online
        }
    }
}
return false; //the device is not online
```